# Overloaded function assigning values to the wrong variables

Tags: c++, overloading

I looked around and did some googling, but I'm having trouble finding the right keywords to find an explanation for my issue. I'm hoping some of you can help. I'm still fairly new and uneducated when it comes to C++, but I felt like when it came to overloading functions I actually had an idea of what to do, but apparently I'm still not quite grasping it.

Basically, I'm trying to overload a function to initialize certain variables to defaults based on what variables are actually provided. I think I might be able to use defaults instead, but I'm having a heck of a time figuring out how they work.

So the actual code looks something like this:

#### foo.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

class Foo
{
private:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    bool boo;
    std::string baz;
public: 
    Foo();
    void init(int _a, int _b, int _c, int _d, bool _boo, std::string _baz);
    void init(int _a, int _b, int _c, bool _boo);
    void init(int _a, int _b, int _d, std::string _baz);
    void printData();
};
```

#### foo.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"

Foo::Foo(){

}

void Foo::init(int _a, int _b, int _c, int _d, bool _boo, std::string _baz) {
    a = _a;
    b = _b;
    c = _c;
    d = _d;
    boo = _boo;
    baz = _baz;
}

void Foo::init(int _a, int _b, int _c, bool _boo) {
    a = _a;
    b = _b;
    c = _c;
    d = 0;
    boo = _boo;
    baz = "";
}

void Foo::init(int _a, int _b, int _d, std::string _baz){
    a = _a;
    b = _b;
    c = -1;
    d = _d;
    boo = 0;
    baz = _baz;
}

void Foo::printData() {
    std::cout << "a = " << a << " | b = " << b << " | c = " << c << " | d = " << d << " | boo = " << boo << " | baz = " << baz << std::endl;
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

Foo foo_1;
Foo foo_2;
Foo foo_3;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    foo_1.init(1,2,3,4,false, "First"); // All variables are set by arguments
    foo_2.init(1,2,3,false); // d and baz are set to a default value
    foo_3.init(1,2,4,"Thrid"); // c and boo are set to a default value

    foo_1.printData();
    foo_2.printData();
    foo_3.printData();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling this code with g++ on a RaspberryPi running Raspbian. The command I'm using is as follows:

```
g++ -o test main.cpp foo.cpp foo.h
```

Now, given my limited knowledge of c++, I expect the output to look something like this:

```
a = 1 | b = 2 | c = 3 | d = 4 | boo = 0 | baz = First
a = 1 | b = 2 | c = 3 | d = 0 | boo = 0 | baz =
a = 1 | b = 2 | c = -1 | d = 4 | boo = 0 | baz = Third
```

But it comes out like this:

```
a = 1 | b = 2 | c = 3 | d = 4 | boo = 0 | baz = First
a = 1 | b = 2 | c = 3 | d = 0 | boo = 0 | baz =
a = 1 | b = 2 | c = 4 | d = 0 | boo = 1 | baz =
```

Could anyone please explain to me where I went wrong and how I should go about fixing it? Thanks!

*As a quick side note; I do realize that the actual initialization could be used in place of my own inits, but in the project I'm actually doing this with, I need the Foo objects at a large scope while still initializing them only after some code has already been run.*

Comment: _As a quick side note;_ no, seriously, `init` functions are a terrible anti-pattern.

Comment: Even though it's not my objective in this post, I would like to hear an alternative to the "init" functions as I'm well aware how bad an idea they actually are.

Comment: ^^ also don't use `_` as prefix, since it's reserved for c++ internal implementations. Using as postfix is OK.

Comment: I'm just doing it to simplify things in my example code. I don't actually do it in real code, just thought it'd be easier to follow for others. That is definitely good to know though.

Comment: Wouldn't [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/578847b8160f1a68) be a far more concise testcase?

Comment: Fair enough, I just copied and refactored my code.

Comment: For an alternative: split that foo into parts, and construct them when it's time to do so.

Comment: And I just refactored it a little more :) You'd have discovered the specific problem if you'd just kept going a little!

Comment: @DanielJour Wouldn't that still limit the scope to the function it's constructed in?

Comment: @Hollish: What you use as an alternative to your "init functions" completely depends on a number of things that we don't know. But, in short, if you're not using constructors and member-initialisation, you're doing it wrong :)

Comment: Sure, but that's not a bad thing. Ideally you could try to achieve a functional style, where you just pass everything into functions. This is often not possible , then you could have one global "resource manager". Though all of this depends on the particular situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quoted "string" is being interpreted as a "const char[6], then const char*" and converted to a boolean instead of an std::string class. You can force the conversion to a string by adding a typecast, e.g.

```
foo_3.init(1,2,4,static_cast<std::string>("Thrid"));
```

Comment: No, `const char[6]`, then `const char*`. Not `char*`, ever.

Comment: Thanks @Anthony! That was my issue all along.